# How do I programmatically hide or show the button in a scene's view controller that seques to next scene

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How do I programmatically hide or show the START SESSION button in a scene's view controller that navigates to the next scene?

[image]

Comment: Did I answer your question or did you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

create an outlet to your button in the view controller class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
```

and then in whichever function you want you can show hide it, I assume you want it hidden by default So in view did load you can do

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    startButton.isHidden = true
}
```

and then show it somewhere else

```
func doSomethingAndShowButton()
{ 
     // Do some other stuff
     ...

     // Show the button
     startButton.isHidden = false 
}
```

Comment: How do I connect actual IB START SESSION button to the IBOutlet?

Comment: Oh sorry you, click on button in the top right that looks like a few rows of lines(its the one up and slightly left of the red error cross in the top right of storyboard). Click that and then click assistant. You should now see code on the right half of the screen, click on your view controller in the storyboard and the code will change to match what your clicking, once your looking at the code for the view controller that has the button on it, right click and drag from the button on storyboard to the class on the right,  you can either link it to an outlet you've written already. or it'll ask

Comment: Equally what @Abdul Rehman has said is equally valid for connecting, basically once you've typed the outlet into code, it'll show in the view Abdul Rehman is showing, if you don't want to type and the then link, you can do as my previous comment says, you can do this to create the outlet or add an action ie a function that will run when the button is pressed etc, if you do it through the drag and drop from storyboard to code everything is linked automatically

Answer (score 0):

[@Doug Null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746100/doug-null) To connect the @IBOutlet. First, follow what [@AngrayDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110338/angryduck) said. After that do as following:

1. Go to the storyboard.
2. Open "Connection inspector" on the right side. Can open through shortcut "Command + Option + 7".
3. Follow the steps highlighted in the below image.

[image]

Hope this helps.